# shell script ssh command not working

Tags: linux, shell, loops, ssh

I have a small list of servers, and I am trying to add a user on each of these servers. I can ssh individually to each server and run the command.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -c "Arun" -d /home/amurug -e 2014-12-12 -g users -u 1470 amurug
```

I wrote a script to loop through the list and run this command but I get some errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter server list: " file

if [[ $file == *linux* ]]; then
  for i in `cat $file`
  do
    echo "creating amurug on" $i
    ssh $i sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -c "Arun" -d /home/amurug -e 2014-12-12 -g users -u 1470 amurug
    echo "==============================================="
    sleep 5
  done
fi
```

When I run the script it does not execute the command.

```
creating amurug on svr102
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN

Options:
```

What is wrong with my ssh crommand in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter server list: " file

if [[ "$file" == *linux* ]]; then
  while read -r server
  do
    echo "creating amurug on" "$server"
    ssh -t -t "$server" "sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -c Arun -d /home/amurug \
       -e 2014-12-12 -g users -u 1470 amurug"
    echo "==============================================="
    sleep 5
  done < "$file"
fi
```

As per `man bash`:

> `-t`
>
> Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.